# Add module to nginx after installation

Tags: centos, streaming, nginx, compile, rtmp

Hi i did install nginx with this command on centos 6

```
sudo yum install nginx
```

and it work but i need to compile wit rtmp module

so How can I find the path to make some changes

```
./configure --add-module=/usr/build/nginx-rtmp-module
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save your nginx configuration files first.

Next

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.9.tar.gz
gunzip http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.9.tar.gz
tar xf nginx-1.9.9
cd nginx-1.9.9
```

And next

```
./configure --add-module=/usr/build/nginx-rtmp-module
```

Afer installing new nginx version check your configs!

Answer (score 0):

rtmp module is statically linked one so it does need to be compiled with nginx. it can't be added dynamically like you are trying to. you need to remove prebuilt version of nginx and compile it from source with rtmp module following documentation.